# electron hole exchange

Tags: quantum-mechanics, exchange-interaction

If exchange is an interaction between indistinguishable particles, how can there be an exchange interaction between electrons and holes? I see mention of e-h exchange often in the literature.

Answer (score 1):

Hole is not a particle. Microscopically, hole is a quasiparticle perturbation of many-electron system. And what is called electron in semiconductors is also a perturbation in the **same** many-electron system. Exchange interaction within this many-electron system results in a complicated interaction between quasiparticles which live there. Which is called exchange interaction because it is quite similar to "normal" exchange interaction.

Comment: I figured it must have been something along those line. Any idea where I could learn more about this?

Comment: @BeauGeste right now I am not ready to give a citation, I will try to find something. In the meantime I'd recommend to search for the papers with _ab initio_ calculations of exchange. They should address this issue.